# How can I make my own Google Chrome Extensions by using C#?

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I have some ideas but C# is language I'm comfortable the most and I have no clue how I can make google extensions in C# ...

Comment: It's kinda incurable as long as you haven't looked close enough to the code, freely available, to know that Webkit is written in C++.  You'll have to make yourself uncomfortable first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say: no way, except if you want to plant Silverlight in the extension

Comment: ok , so what is silverlight ? 
is it like C# ?

Comment: @Pedrum: Google is your friend! http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html they aren't hard to build (the basic ones of course) at all.The difference between C# and Silverlight is very easily found with simple searches. Just basic searches like http://goo.gl/xxjvT and http://goo.gl/FV7mp will through you in the right direction.

Comment: Although it might be worth pointing out that `the difference between C# and Silverlight` does not make much sense. You probably meant: the difference between the .NET framework and Silverlight

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Chrome extensions are written in HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. See: [What are extensions?](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

Since C# could be translated into javascript (which is a core component of Chrome extensions) you can partly use it to write business logic of your extension and then augment it with html, css and so on.

See [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp) for details.